# How to access GMail API from my own GMail?

Tags: javascript, google-api, gmail-api, vert.x

If I try to call the GMail API, I get the following error in return:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [{
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "failedPrecondition",
            "message": "Bad Request"
        }],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Bad Request"
    }
}
```

First I generate a token

```
var sHead = JSON.stringify({
    "alg": "RS256",
    "typ": "JWT"
});
var iat = timeStampf();
var exp = iat + 3600;
var sPayload = JSON.stringify({
    "iss": client_email,
    "sub": client_email,
    "scope": "https://mail.google.com/",
    "aud": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token",
    "exp": exp,
    "iat": iat
});
var sJWS = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign("RS256", sHead, sPayload, private_key);
var paramstoken = "grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=" + sJWS


getToken("POST", "/oauth2/v3/token", paramstoken, jsonData, replier);
/*rest petition
return 200 ok {
    "access_token": "1/8xbJqaOZXSUZbHLl5EOtu1pxz3fmmetKx9W8CV4t79M",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600
}
*/
```

Next I test the token

```
function testToken(accessToken, replier) {
    var client = vertx.createHttpClient().host(urlbase).port(443).ssl(true).maxPoolSize(10);
    var request = client.request("GET", "/gmail/v1/users/me/messages", function(resp) {
        console.log('server returned status code: ' + resp.statusCode());
        console.log('server returned status message: ' + resp.statusMessage());
        resp.bodyHandler(function(body) {
            replier(JSON.parse(body.toString()));
        });
    });
    request.headers()
        .set("Content-type", contentType)
        .set("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    request.end();
    client.close();
}
```

And I get an error 400 bad request in return. But if I use a different scope, for example Google+, I get a 200 ok.

I think the error is '"sub":client_email'. I tried add more GMails in the Google console, and with 3 mails auto create for the project, only the mail from Json return me failed precondition if try with others mails including auto created for project and my own GMail(the GMail owner of project) error is 401 unautorized_client.

Or do I need other "grant_type  Use the following string, URL-encoded as necessary: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"?

```
de13@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
7686@developer.gserviceaccount.com///this is de mail downloaded in json from credentials
768-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

(this is server side js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems with your OAauth credentials. On Google Developer Console -> Credentials, when you try to get new credentials, there are 3 options, 1) Web Application (This is the one you should be using) 2) Service Account (Which is I believe you are trying to use right now), 3) Installed Application (For iOS & Android apps)

Also while authenticating, mention that you will be trying to access the service content in 'offline' mode, which will give you a 'refresh Token' to make subsquent requests without user's involvment.

You are able to access Google+ because its public data as compared to Gmail where you are trying to access messages for a certain user (Private data). Service account credentials will not give you access to a user's private data and you must impersonate the user whose emails you are trying to access via authentication using Web Application credentials in your case.

Hope this helps....

Comment: i use optioon 2 'Service Account' and use this guide https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: @VictorManuel Are you using a Google App Domain? Because that is the only case where you can access user's private data via a Service Account otherwise you would need to impersonate the user via a 3-way OAuth cycle where user is first redirected to Google Authentication screen by your script, where user login and grant access to you application to view his/her emails.

Comment: I will try with 1) web application, ty

Answer (score 1):

```
"sub": client_email
```

seems to be incorrect.

You should use your gmail address in the sub field, as you are trying to impersonate this email address.

Comment: yes, i try it, with my email, another mail adress and the  3 auto created mail for google console, only with "client_email" and without "sub " return me 200 ok, if i try with my gmail return "Unautorized client"

Comment: Have you also given the service account domain wide authority in the Google Admin console? You also need to use an email address from this domain in the sub field.

Comment: i dont have domain, i will try with Web Application option for access, ty